# In line assembler method crashing the entire program

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I´m having problems with assembly. Currently using VC++ 2015 x86 compiler and inline assembler to translate a method from C. The C method is running perfectly and as intended:

```c
void calculateCRC(Info *data, int lonDiv, unsigned char divisor)
{
    unsigned char a = divisor;
    unsigned char b = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data->dataLength; i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = 128;
        while (a != 0)
        {
            if (data->content[i] & c)
            {
                data->content[i] = data->content[i] ^ a;
                data->content[i + 1] = data->content[i + 1] ^ b;
            }
            char carry = a << 7;
            b = b >> 1;
            b = b | carry;
            a = a >> 1;
            c = c >> 1;
        }
        a = b;
        b = 0;
    }
}
```

Some side notes:

- The Info struct only has an int declared dataLength and a pointer to a char array declared as *content.
- I know that the lonDiv parameter is not being used, yet I can't change the function declarations.

With that in mind, I tried to translate as best as I could yet it does not function. The method ends up failing and the whole program crashes, not even returning an error code, it simply crashes. The code is as follows.

```
void calculateCRC(Info *data, int lonDiv, unsigned char divisor)
{
    __asm {
        push ax // a and b
        push dx // content[i] and content[i+1]
        push cx // c and carry
        push esi // Index var
        push edi // Pointer to content
        push ebx // Pointer to dataLength

        mov ah, [ebp + 16] //a = divisor
        mov al, 0 // b = 0
        mov esi, 0 //int i = 0

        forLoop: // for
            mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
            cmp esi, [ebx] // i < data->dataLength

            jz end
            whileLoop:
                mov ch, 128 // c = 128
                cmp ah, 0 // while (a != 0)
                je cutWhile
            mov edi, [ebp + 8] // Info *data
            add edi, 4 // data->content
            mov dh, [edi + esi] // content[i]
            mov dl, [edi + esi + 1] // content[i+1]
            test dh, ch // if (content[i] & c)
            jz next
                xor dh, ah // data->content[i] ^ a;
                xor dl, al // data->content[i + 1] ^ b;
                mov [edi + esi], dh // data->content[i] = data->content[i] ^ a;
                mov [edi + esi + 1], dl // data->content[i + 1] = data->content[i + 1] ^ b;
                next:
                    mov cl, ah // char carry = a
                    shl cl, 7 // carry = carry << 7
                    shr al, 1 // b = b >> 1
                    or al, cl // b = b | carry
                    shr ah, 1 // a = a >> 1
                    shr ch, 1 // c = c >> 1
                    jmp whileLoop
            cutWhile:
                shl ax, 8 // a = b and b = 0
                inc esi //i++
                jmp forLoop
        end:
            pop ebx
            pop edi
            pop esi
            pop cx
            pop dx
            pop ax
            ret
    }
}
```

I am no assembler expert, but I have tried to translate and comment out everything to no avail. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: That's quite straight-forward program, you are unlikely to write better code than the compiler. Any reason why you want assembly, and inline assembly in particular? As for the crash, use a debugger to pinpoint the location and also single step the code. Note that depending on compiler and settings you might not even have `ebp` set up so you can't access arguments relative to that. You should really write a standalone assembly module if you insist on assembly at all. Oh, and you should not push 16 bit registers in 32 bit code.

Comment: Visual C++  allows you to access C++ variables by name within the inline assembly.

Comment: (**note:** when formatting code with `\`\`\``, you need to add the language at the end, e.g. `\`\`\`c` of `\`\`\`asm`, to preserve syntax highlighting)

Comment: All that said, I think one of your problems is that you are missing a dereference of `data->content`, that is replace `add edi, 4` with `mov edi, [edi + 4]`.

Comment: I need to use assembly and inline assembly because it is an assignment for uni. As for ```epb```, VC++ x86 compiler automatically pushes it and does ```mov ebp, esp```. As for the debugging, I'm not sure how to debug it. Could you recommend a tool or program for debugging inline assembler?

Comment: Visual studio has built in debugger which can show assembly.

Comment: After lots of trials and error, I managed to get the debugger going, but is there any way to visualize the stack while debugging?

Comment: The,VS debugger has a stack frame pane, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

(turning comments into an answer; the Godbolt links are a bit random and scattered.)

*If* you wantd to write a whole function yourself in asm including a `ret`, [use `__declspec(naked)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/naked-cpp?view=vs-2019) to stop the compiler from emitting any prologue/epilogue so the entire function body is really just your `asm` block.  Then you need to set up `ebp` as a frame pointer yourself, if you want to use it that way.

(Or not; this function needs a lot of registers so you could omit the frame pointer like optimizing compilers do.  But you can save regs by optimizing away the `carry` into a simple 16-bit shift, with your vars in AH, AL, CH, CL, and so on, and take advantage of 16-bit or 32-bit operand-size to do 2 8-bit operations at once..)

**Using your own `ret` is a bug because ESP is pointing at some regs the compiler saved, unless you're writing a naked function**.

Use Visual Studio's debugger to see what's really going on, preferably with an asm / disassembly view so you can see your code from inline asm in the context of the surrounding compiler-generated code.  (You'll see your `ret` then the compiler-generated `pop`s and compiler-generated `ret` that it was expecting would run after your asm block finished with ESP unmodified)

**I'd recommend not using your own push/pop or your own ret** (so *not* a naked function), and use the C++ variable names inside your asm statement so you can watch them with the debugger by their C++ names, instead of looking at raw stack memory at all.  (But using the debugger's asm / disassembly view, you *can* see how something like `mov ebx, data` compiles to probably still the `mov ebx, [ebp + 8]` like you wrote.)

As Jester points out, **`add edi, 4` is also a bug**: that would make sense if you had `struct Info { int len; uint8_t content[1020]; };` so the content address is just a small offset from the base of the struct.  But you said you have `uint8_t *content;` so you need another load from the struct, like `mov edi, [edi+4]`.  Look at what compilers do for the pure C++ version: https://godbolt.org/z/aVdsED (or use a lower optimization level like `-O1`).

You don't need to keep reloading this pointer inside the loop; that doesn't make sense.  Keep the current position in `content` in a register, and keep an end-pointer in another register (or memory if you run out of registers).  i.e. spill something that's read-only and can be used as a memory operand inside the loop.  So at worst your outer loop becomes `cmp edi, [endp]` / `jb top_of_loop` instead of a compare between two registers.

---

Not a real bug (just overcomplication), **but you don't need to manually push/pop registers at the start/end of your asm block** (unless you write a naked function). MSVC will generate code around the function containing the asm block to save/restore any register that need saving, which means they're also free for compiler-generated use.

In fact it will do that anyway because pop edi writes EDI, and it doesn't try to prove that the inline asm matches up push and pop and doesn't modify the saved copy in memory. See https://godbolt.org/z/j5b4W- note the compiler-generated part of the compiler output.

---

It looks like you can simplify that manual-carry stuff into `shr ax, 1`, with `a:b` in `AH:AL` = AX.  A lot of your other instructions are doing 16-bit stuff 8 bits at a time, like loading AL and AH from 2 contiguous bytes in memory which could be `mov ax, mem`.

But for the actual memory access to `content[]`, compilers don't do it that way. Instead they notice that `content[i+1]` in one iteration is `content[i]` in the next iteration, and `mov reg,reg` instead of storing and reloading. https://godbolt.org/z/aVdsED.

This is much better; overlapping store/reload is inefficient. But anyway, using ax as `a:b` would be efficient, shifting 1 bit at a time until `test ah,ah` finds you've shifted all the bits out.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback! As soon as I manage to get it running, I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

After reading and the kind help of the community, I finally managed to get it running as I intended. The fixed code is as follows:

```
void calculateCRC(Info *data, int lonDiv, unsigned char divisor)
{   
    __asm {
        mov eax, 0
        mov ah, [ebp + 16] //a = divisor
        mov al, 0 // b = 0
        mov esi, 0 //int i = 0

        forLoop: // for
            mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
            cmp esi, [ebx] // i < data->dataLength

            jz end
            mov ch, 128 // c = 128
            whileLoop:
                cmp ah, 0 // while (a != 0)
                je cutWhile
            mov edi, [ebp + 8] // Info* data
            mov edi, [edi + 4] // data->content
            mov dh, [edi + esi] // content[i]
            mov dl, [edi + esi + 1] // content[i+1]
            test dh, ch // if (content[i] & c)
            jz next
                xor dh, ah // data->content[i] ^ a;
                xor dl, al // data->content[i + 1] ^ b;
                mov [edi + esi], dh // data->content[i] = data->content[i] ^ a;
                mov [edi + esi + 1], dl // data->content[i + 1] = data->content[i + 1] ^ b;
                next:
                    mov cl, ah // char carry = a
                    shl cl, 7 // carry = carry << 7
                    shr al, 1 // b = b >> 1
                    or al, cl // b = b | carry
                    shr ah, 1 // a = a >> 1
                    shr ch, 1 // c = c >> 1
                    jmp whileLoop
            cutWhile:
                shl ax, 8 // a = b and b = 0
                inc esi //i++
                jmp forLoop
        end:
    }
}
```

Changes:

- Removed `pop/push` operations and let the compiler do that job.
- Removed `ret` operation.
- Changed `add edi, 4` to `mov edi, [edi + 4]`.

There is still room for improvement, such as the manual carry operation pointed by Peter on his comments and answer afterward. Yet I will leave it as is for the time being. Thanks a lot to Jester and Peter Cordes for their time and comments.

Comment: You're still using `mov ah, [ebp + 16]` instead of `mov ah, divisor`.  It's usually a bad idea to use EBP directly.  What if this function inlines into another function that has its locals in different places on the stack?